# computing $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \frac{e^{x^2-y^2} -1}{ x - y}$ without Taylor series

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

how can i compute this limit without using Taylor series?

$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \frac{e^{x^2-y^2} -1}{ x - y}$, while $x\neq y$.

i tried to put $r^2=x^2-y^2$ and transfer to polar but it didn't work for me.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by $f(u)=(\exp(u)-1)/u$ if $u\not =0$, and $f(0)=1$. Then $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$(to show that, we need only use that the derivative of $\exp(u)$ at $u=0$ is $1$). We have $uf(u)=\exp(u)-1$ for all $u\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $g$ your function: we have
$$g(x,y)=\frac{(x^2-y^2)f(x^2-y^2)}{x-y}=(x+y)f(x^2-y^2)$$
Hence $g(x,y)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the product of two continuous functions, it is easy to finish: the limit is $0\times 1=0$.

Comment: @Mirko ? I do not understand your comment. Can you explain ?

Comment: @Mirko Ok, thanks, This was a typo. I have edited.

Comment: In your second line, you have written $\exp(x^2-y^2)-\exp(x-y)=\exp(x-y)(\exp(x+y)-1)$

Comment: thank you for pointing out my mistake, I will leave my answer as is, though I added a comment there that  mine is wrong, yours is right

Comment: @Mirko, Ok, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

(Edit. The following answer is incorrect, the error is indicated in the comments.)

I don't think the limit exists, as you obtain different values along different paths, as shown below.

$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \dfrac{e^{x^2-y^2} -1}{ x - y} = 
\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \dfrac{e^{(x+y)(x-y)} -e^{x-y}+e^{x-y}  -1}{ x - y} =$
$=\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \dfrac{e^{x-y}(e^{x+y} -1)}{ x - y} + 
\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \dfrac{e^{x-y}  -1}{ x - y}$.

Now $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \dfrac{e^{x-y}  -1}{ x - y}=1$ and 
$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} e^{x-y}=1$. But $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \dfrac{(e^{x+y} -1)}{ x - y}$ does not exist, as it has different values along different paths, as shown below.

For example, first look at the constraint $y=\frac12x$. Then $x-y=\frac12x$ and $x+y=\frac32x$. So $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \dfrac{(e^{x+y} -1)}{ x - y} = \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \dfrac{(e^{\frac32x} -1)}{ \frac12x} = 
\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \dfrac{3(e^{\frac32x} -1)}{ \frac32x}=3$, along the path $y=\frac12x$.

Now look at the constraint (or path) $y=\frac14x$. Then $x-y=\frac34x$ and $x+y=\frac54x$. So $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \dfrac{(e^{x+y} -1)}{ x - y} = \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \dfrac{(e^{\frac54x} -1)}{ \frac34x} = 
\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \dfrac{5(e^{\frac54x} -1)}{ 3\cdot\frac54x}=\dfrac53\not=3$, along the path $y=\frac14x$.

Since the value of the limit should be independent of the path along which the limit is evaluated, the above shows that the limit does not exist.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i didn't understand why i can't say: $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{e^z-1}z \cdot \frac{e^z}{1}=1$. if $x=-y$ it doesn't matter because it's continuous and tends to zero.

Comment: My answer is wrong (but got voted up anyway :), go read the answer by @Kelenner which looks right to me. He pointed to my mistake in the comments there, as I asked. Namely I wrote $e^{(x+y)(x-y)} -e^{x-y}= e^{(x+y)}(e^{x-y} -1)$, which is incorrect. It would have been correct that $e^{(x+y)+(x-y)} -e^{x-y}= e^{(x+y)}(e^{x-y} -1)$ but the latter does not apply to this problem.

Comment: ok thank you for the effort, but still am i right about my comment? because at first one wrote an answer like that and someone pointed him out that if $x=-y$ he have a problem, while $z=x^2-y^2$.

Comment: Well you could use that $x=-y$ doesn't matter, but you have to say something about it and justify that indeed it doesn't matter. If you don't say anything then it is an omission, and most often an error (since usually it matters a lot). If you explain in detail why it doesn't matter (for a particular problem) then you could use the $0\cdot1=1$ approach, as in the other answers. So you were right it could be done without Taylor series :)

Comment: glad to hear that, thank you!

Comment: ... and $0\cdot1=0$, not $1$ :) done with MSE for today, making too many errors. You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

By making the substitution $z = e^{x^2-y^2}-1$, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow (0, 0)}\frac{e^{x^2-y^2}-1}{x^2-y^2} &= \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{z}{\ln(1+z)}\\
&= \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\ln\left((1+z)^{1/z}\right)}\\
&=1.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow (0, 0)}\frac{e^{x^2-y^2}-1}{x-y} &= \lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow (0, 0)}\frac{e^{x^2-y^2}-1}{x^2-y^2} \frac{x^2-y^2}{x-y}\\
&=\lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow (0, 0)}\frac{e^{x^2-y^2}-1}{x^2-y^2} (x+y)\\
&=\lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow (0, 0)}\frac{e^{x^2-y^2}-1}{x^2-y^2} \lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow (0, 0)}(x+y)\\
&=0.
\end{align*}